# execute and receive the output of mml command in c++

Tags: c++, c, parsing

i have an interface where i use to execute the mml command in my solaris unix like below:

```
> eaw 0004
<RLTYP; 
BSC SYSTEM TYPE DATA

GSYSTYPE
GSM1800

END
<
```

As soon as i do `eaw <name>` on the command line.It will start an interface where in i can execute mml commands and i can see the output of those commands executed.

My idea here is to parse the command output in c++.
I can do away with some logic for parsing.But to start with How can get the command to be executed inside c++ ? Is there any predefined way to do this.
This should be similar to executing sql queries inside c++.But we use other libraries to execute sql queries.I also donot want to run a shell script or create temporary files in between.

what i want is to execute the command inside c++ and get the output and even that in c++.
could anybody give me the right directions?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.  From easiest and simplest to hardest and most complex to use:

- Use the [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) call to spawn a shell to run a command
- Use the [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) call to spawn a subprocess and either write to its standard input stream or read from its standard output stream (but not both)
- Use a combination of [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html#), [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html), [`dup()`/`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html), and [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) to spawn a child process and set up pipes for a child process's standard input and output.

Comment: @adam.Thanks for your suggestion.could you pls give me a small example .lets say executing sql query inside c++ using the above mentioned suggestions.?

Answer (score 0):

The below code is done with the `sh` command. This redirects `stdout` to a file named "out" which can be read later to process the output. Each command to the process can be written through the pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        FILE *fp;
        fp = popen("sh > out", "w");
        if (fp) {
                fprintf(fp, "date\n");
                fprintf(fp, "exit\n");
                fclose(fp);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just like execute a shell command.i cannot start an interface and execute command through this.also its creting a file "out" which i already mentioned i donot wish to do.